# get all facebook friendslist with name and id in json string

Tags: android, json, facebook

Currently I am signing in to facebook like this. I need  friendslist belonging to that loggd in user. How do i do that?

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new  Session.StatusCallback() {
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if(session.isOpened()){
                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback(){
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                           if(user != null){
                            fb_login_button.setText("Login as "+user.getFirstName());
 }
                        else{

                        }
                    }                   

                });
            }           
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Request.newMyFriendsRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#newMyFriendsRequest%28Session,%20GraphUserListCallback%29) method.